Probability of rolling under a value using 2D10
First time caller, go easy on me.
I'm trying to establish and clarify some probability statistics using ten sided dice.
Using a system of two, fair, ten sided dice (2d10), where the first represents units and the second dice is tens and 0 & 0 is considered to be "100". So 8 and 2 is considered "82".
I understand that probability of rolling 27 is 1%
favourable outcomes / total outcomes. Which is 1/10 * 1/10 = 0.01 As a percentage multiply by 100, which is 1%
So far so good - If that were a graph of percentage & rolled dice values it would be a straight line.
However... things maybe slightly different now that I want to calculate the probability of rolling "at least" 27. And I may have gone hideously wrong at this point.
Looking at a table

there are 76 chances over what I assume to be a constant total outcomes of 100. Which is 76/100. So the probability or rolling under 27 is 0.76%
Or have I totally put a spanner in the works?
My plan is to A) confirm the correct way of calculating this (I don't think I'm right) and secondly B) work out all probability values from 1 to 100 in Excel and/or Python later.

On what basis have you marked the lines?

At least means x<=27 then the answer is 27%. You must count only the overlapping lines

Also since there are 99 possible outcomes (1-100) that are equally possible, the graph would be a straight horizontal line.

@Aatmaj:  there are $100$ possible outcomes, not $99$

Certainly there are $26$ numbers under $27$, one equal to $27$, and $73$ greater than $27$ so the chance of greater than $27$ is $73\%$.
Presumably the horizontal axis is the tens die and the vertical axis is the ones die.  Your purple stripes try to get all the numbers where either the tens digit is two or less or the ones digit is seven or less but did not think about the fact that the $10$ row and column represent $0$.  The numbers less than $27$ on your chart are the whole column $1$, the column $2$ up through $6$ plus $10$, and the whole column $10$ except $10$.  You have marked $41$ in purple but not $49$, for example.

Basically you can start with the tens. If the tens are greater or equal than $3$, then the number is a favorable number, a number greater or equal to $30$. These are the green crossed cells and represent the numbers greater or equal than $30$. The combination $(0/0)$ represent the number $100$. The missing numbers are  $28$ and $29$, which are the blue crossed cells. Now you can count the cross filled cells.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline \text{tens / units } &0  & 1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7&8&9 \\ \hline\hline \hline 0 &\color{green}X&&&&&&\\\hline 1 &&&&&&& \\  \hline 2 &&&&&&&&&\color{blue}X&\color{blue}X \\ \hline 3 &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X} \\ \hline 4  &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}  \\ \hline  5 &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X} \\ \hline 6&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X} \\ \hline 7 &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}\\ \hline 8 &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}\\\hline 9&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X} &\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}&\color{green}{X}\\ \hline\end{array}$$
